# How to list specific type of files in recursive directories in shell?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, command-line, command

How can we find specific type of files i.e. doc pdf files present in nested directories.

command I tried:

```
$ ls -R | grep .doc
```

but if there is a file name like `alok.doc.txt` the command will display that too which is obviously not what I want.  What command should I use instead?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you are more confortable with "ls" and "grep", you can do what you want using a regular expression in the grep command (the ending '$' character indicates that .doc must be at the end of the line. That will exclude "file.doc.txt"):

```
ls -R |grep "\.doc$"
```

More information about using grep with regular expressions in [the man](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/grep).

Comment: probably good to escape the dot, otherwise a file like `hellodoc` would also match. `ls -R | grep "\.doc$"`

Comment: Is there a way to have this show you the full path of a file that `ls` finds?  Right now I just a list of all the files, but I don't know how to actually go find them now.

Comment: never, ever use `ls` as input data in scripts

Comment: @MestreLion I can't see how it can be harmful if the input is handled by `grep`

Comment: @MehdiCharife because `ls` is meant for _humans_, and as such can be heavily customized with environment vars, so its output is unpredictable. [Greg's WIki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) has a comprehensive explanation of the caveats and suggestions. `find` is more stable, globbing (with `globstar` enabled) is even better.

Answer (score 35):

`ls` command output is mainly intended for reading by humans.  For advanced querying for automated processing, you should use more powerful `find` command:

```
find /path -type f \( -iname "*.doc" -o -iname "*.pdf" \)
```

As if you have bash 4.0++

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*.{pdf,doc}
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: It's **/*.pdf **/*.doc - you are not recursing into the the sub directories without it

Comment: You can do `ls **/*.{pdf,doc}` or `for file in **/*.{pdf,doc}`

Comment: Wow, I typed in three asterisks and it replaced it with one - something to know in the future.

Answer (score 8):

```
find . | grep "\.doc$"
```

This will show the path as well.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other methods that can be used:

`echo *.{pdf,docx,jpeg}`

`stat -c %n * | grep 'pdf\|docx\|jpeg'`

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar question. We wanted a list - with paths - of all the config files in the etc directory. This worked:

```
find /etc -type f \( -iname "*.conf" \)
```

It gives a nice list of all the .conf file with their path. Output looks like:

```
/etc/conf/server.conf
```

But, we wanted to DO something with ALL those files, like grep those files to find a word, or setting, in all the files. So we use

```
find /etc -type f \( -iname "*.conf" \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Hi "ServerName"
```

to find via grep ALL the config files in /etc that contain a setting like "ServerName" Output looks like:

```
/etc/conf/server.conf: ServerName "default-118_11_170_172"
```

Hope you find it useful.

Sid

Answer (score 0):

If you have files with extensions that don't match the file type, you could use the `file` utility.

`find $PWD -type f -exec file -N \{\} \; | grep "PDF document" | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

Instead of `$PWD` you can use the directory you want to start the search in. `file` prints even out he PDF version.