# How to ls all the files in the subdirectories using wildcard?

Tags: linux, ls

`ls *` can list all the files in the **subdirectories**.

`ls *.pdb` can only list all the files with extension `pdb` in the **current** directory.

So how to list all the files with extension `pdb` in the **subdirectories**?

My subdirectories are named as `1`, `2`, `3`, .... I would like the output also include the directory information, so that I can use the output as an ensemble of input files. For example, the output should be like:

`1/a.pdb 1/b.pdb 1/c.pdb 2/a.pdb 2/b.pdb 2/c.pdb 3/a.pdb 3/b.pdb 3/c.pdb`

Comment: `ls */*.pdb`. You can also enable `dotglob` and use `**` as the wildcard for all subdirectores (with bash). Otherwise, you use `find -type f -name "*.pdb"` to locate all `.pdb` files in nested subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Could you please post the answer?

Comment: Or use `find`, if you have more than 1 level of subdirectories: `find . -name \*.pdb`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively search for files with certain extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5985752/608639), [Recursively look for files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927369/608639), [How to list specific type of files in recursive directories in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528460/608639), [List all files in a directory with a certain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18823609/608639), [List files with certain extensions with ls and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447625/608639), etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

3 solutions :

#### Simple `glob`

```
ls */*.pdb
```

#### Recursive using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
shopt -s globstar
ls **/*.pdb
```

#### Recursive using [find](/questions/tagged/find)

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
locate */*.pdb
```

Its for previously made database

You can see the difference, if you code some Python and right after that use both

```
locate */*.py
ls */*.py
```

Comment: You can't be sure that `updatedb` have been executed before, and it's mandatory to create index