# Why does ls not subset by filetype recursively (with -R)?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, zsh, ls

I want to list all .jpg files in all subdirectories using `ls`.

For the same directory this works fine:

`ls *.jpg`

However, when using the `-R` for recursiveness:

`ls -R *.jpg`

I get:

`zsh:no matches found: *.jpg`

Why does this not work?

*Note: I know it can be done using [`find` or `grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528460/how-to-list-specific-type-of-files-in-recursive-directories-in-shell) but I want to know why the above does not work.*

Comment: BTW, another working example with zsh is `ls **/*.jpg`. The fact that it requires zsh (or bash 4.0+ with the non-default `globstar` option enabled) to work -- despite the `ls` executable being exactly the same no matter which shell you're using -- should give you a big hint about why your original command _didn't_ work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell first expands any glob patterns, and then runs the command. So from `ls`'s perspective, `ls *.jpg` is exactly the same as if you had typed `ls one.jpg two.jpg`. The `-R` flag to `ls` only makes sense if you use it on a directory, which you're not doing here.

This is also why `mv *.jpg *.png` doesn't work as expected on Unix systems, since `mv` never sees those patterns but just the filenames it expanded to (it does on e.g. Windows, where the globbing is done by the program rather than the shell; there are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches).

---

`*` matches all characters *except* a `/`, so `*.jpg` only expands to patterns in the current directory. `**/` is similar, but also matches `/`, so it expands to patterns in any directory. This is supported by both bash and zsh.

So `ls **/*.jpg` will do what you want; you don't need to use `find` or `grep`. In zsh, especially you rarely need to use `find` since globbing is so much more powerful than in the standard Bourne shell or bash.

In zsh you can also use `setopt glob_star_short` and then `**.jpg` will work as well, which is a shortcut for `**/*.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

The program `ls` is not designed to handle patterns by itself.

When you run `ls -R *.jpg`, the pattern `*.jpg` is not directly passed to `ls`. The shell replaces it by a list of all files that match the pattern. (Only if there is no file with a matching name, `ls` will see the file name `*.jpg` and not find a file of this name.)
Since you are using `zsh` (with the default setting `setopt nomatch`), it prints an error message instead of passing the pattern to `ls`.

If there are matching files, e.g. `A.jpg`, `B.jpg`, `C.jpg`, the command

```
ls *.jpg
```

will be run by the shell as

```
ls A.jpg B.jpg C.jpg
```

In contrast to this, `find` is designed to handle patterns with its `-name` test.  When using `find` you should make sure the pattern is *not*  replaced by the shell, e.g. by using `-name '*.jpg'` or `-name \*.jpg`. Otherwise you might get unexpected results or an error if there are matching files in the current directory.

---

**Edit:**
As shown in [Martin Tournoij's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74006982/10622916) you could use the recursive glob pattern `ls **/*.jpg`, but this is also handled by the shell not by `ls`, so you don't need option `-R`. In `zsh` this recursive pattern `**` is enabled by default, in `bash` you need to enable it with `shopt -s globstar`.